# how to set multiple default form values on submission in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5

`attendance` table that takes has attribute **status**, **date**,**recuritment_id**, and **project_site_id** .

`project_site` has **one_to_many** association with `attendance`

`recuritment`has one_to_many association with `attendance`.

i am taking attribute from `recruitment` table when attribute `status` is joined in attendance#form view.

`<% (1..(Time.days_in_month @project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%m").to_i)).each do |date| %>`
here **@project_site.attendance_month** contains the attendance month value. based on month i calculate number of days column along with `name` from `recuritmnet` table.

here is view-

[image]

**holydays** master contains corresponding month holyday's date and in view it auto match date and prints "H", 
All input default selected as P. there is final submission_button that chnages boolean attribute. now on final submission i want to push all default selected **P** into attendance table.

attendance_controller.rb

```
  def new
    if @project_site.submission_status == false
      @attendance = Attendance.new

      @date = HolydayCalendar.all

      @recruitment = Recruitment.all.where(current_status: "2")
    else
      redirect_to project_site_attendances_path
    end
  end
```

from.html.erb (attendance controller view)

```
<table>
   <thead>
      <tr>
         <th class="attendance-emp-name">Emp. Name</th>
         <% (1..(Time.days_in_month @project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%m").to_i)).each do |date| %>
         <th class="text-center"><%= date %></th>
         <% end %>
      </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
      <% @recruitment.where(location: @project_site.site_id).each do |recruitment| %>
      <tr>
         <td class="attendance-emp-name"><%= recruitment.name %></td>
         <% (1..(Time.days_in_month @project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%m").to_i)).each do |date| %>
         <%= form_with(model: attendance, :html => {:id => 'attendance-form-validation'}, url:[@project_site, @attendance], local: true) do |f| %>
         <% if HolydayCalendar.find_by(date: (@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%Y-%m")+"-"+date.to_s), total_site_id: @project_site.site_id)%>
         <td class="holyday text-center"><%= "H" %></td>
         <% elsif recruitment.attendances.find_by(attendance_date: (@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%Y-%m")+"-"+date.to_s)) == nil %>
         <td>
            <%= f.select :status, [['P', 1], ['A', 2], ['L', 4], ['WE', 5], ['CO', 6]], {}, { onchange: 'this.form.submit()', class: 'attendance-select-input' } %>
         </td>
         <% else %>
         <% attendance_value =  recruitment.attendances.find_by(attendance_date: (@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%Y-%m")+"-"+date.to_s)) %>
         <%if attendance_value.status == 1 %>
         <td class="presant text-center"><%="P" %></td>
         <% elsif attendance_value.status == 2 %>
         <td class="absent text-center"><%="A" %></td>
         <%elsif attendance_value.status == 3 %>
         <td class="holyday text-center"><%="H" %></td>
         <%elsif attendance_value.status == 4 %>
         <td class="leave text-center"><%= "L" %></td>
         <%elsif attendance_value.status == 5 %>
         <td class="weekend text-center"><%= "WE" %></td>
         <%elsif attendance_value.status == 6 %>
         <td class="compoff text-center"><%= "CO" %></td>
         <% end %>
         <% end %>
         <%= f.hidden_field :attendance_date, value: (@project_site.attendance_month.strftime("%Y-%m")+"-"+date.to_s)%>
         <%=f.hidden_field :recruitment_id, value: recruitment.id%>
         <%=f.hidden_field :project_site_id, value: @project_site.id%>
         <% end %>
         <% end %>
      </tr>
      <% end %>
   </tbody>
</table>
<% if @project_site.submission_status == true %>
<div class="text-center">
   <%= link_to "Submit Attendance", set_submission_status_project_site_path(@project_site), method: :put, data: { confirm: 'Make Sure you marked all attendance before submission' }, :class=>"button primary disabled" %>
</div>
<% else %>
<div class="text-center">
   <%= link_to "Submit Attendance", set_submission_status_project_site_path(@project_site), method: :put, data: { confirm: 'Make Sure you marked all attendance before submission' }, :class=>"button primary" %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

project_sites_controller.rb

```
  def set_submission_status
      @project_site = ProjectSite.find(params[:id])
      @project_site.update(submission_status: true)

  end
```

Comment: I'd love to help but unfortunately from your description, I don't have any idea what you're trying to achieve. Also, your code formatting seems to be all over the place and a crucial piece (your model code) seems to be missing. I suggest you 1) clean up the code (proper indentation/alignment etc.), 2) you share the model code, 3) you clarify your requirements (e.g. a table, which output you'd expect for a certain input).

Comment: I'm trying to understand your code, but it's a bit difficult. Let me urge you to refactor the form, there's just way too much logic in the view. Most of this logic should be in the model(s) and perhaps (less preferable) in the controller. You will definitely appreciate it later, when you have to maintain the code. And you might also be able to get better help from SO too! And finally, as @ClemensKofler has mentioned, make your question easier to read... it helps those of us who are willing to help you.

Comment: @ClemensKofler formatted code. i am taking ```attendace``` from form view of attendance controller. if attendance is marked then i access marked value. if not marked yet then i show them i drop-drown with default selected ```P```.  there is a final submission button on final submission i want to set all ```P``` value into database, currently i identify ```P``` as if it is null.

Comment: The following is difficult for me to understand -- are you able to reword it? See here: "on submission of attendance project_site model attribute submission_status attribute changes. On submit attendance click, i want to set all default selected value of P into status attribute of attendance table. all p value i want to push into table not H value. Current Form Code is show below-" what is p? what is h? etc.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon. as per code - ```<%= f.select :status, [['P', 1], ['A', 2], ['L', 4], ['WE', 5], ['CO', 6]], {}, { onchange: 'this.form.submit()', class: 'attendance-select-input' } %>``` this creates a drop-down with key-value pair, data gets submitted on user event to ```attendance``` table. here p is default selected. on  final submission i want all value of P selected with their corresponding value should be submitted once.

Comment: @rock - are you able to upload a video explaining and showing? Is there a friend or colleague who can help you rewrite the question? There are three people already having trouble understanding. my two cents.

Comment: @BKSpurgeon added more explanation hope i am able to make it simple now.

Comment: @rock buddy i can't help you with this one.........unfortunately I am not able to understand what you have written :'(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little unclear what your question is, but I gather it has to do with your form sending back an array op options.

If you want your html form to return an array of information, then you need to indicate it in your html using the `name = "attendance[]"` syntax, notice the square brackets.

Check out this article on the subject https://mattstauffer.com/blog/a-little-trick-for-grouping-fields-in-an-html-form/